# Remove rows where at least x percent of the values are zero in both groups

Tags: r

Given the following dataframe i would like to remove all rows with at least x percent (e.g 50%) of values = 0 in at least one group.

For example if a row has less than 50% of values in both groups (control and treatment) it will be removed.

If the row has 50% of non zero value in group control(or treatment) and no values in the other group it will be kept since there is still one group with at least 50% values.

Hope it´s clear.

```
    treatment   control control treatment control treatment
row1    0 21   21   21    45 34
row2    0 21   78   321   93 0
row3 34 32  98   87    34 0
row4    75 21  12   54    45 34
row5    46 21  13   45     0   0
row6    85 21  87   45     0 23 
row7    24 84   0    0    45 5
row8    87 21   0    98   87 76
row9   43  2   0    45   12 9
row10    12 12   0    0    23  0
```

Here below the dataframe

```
 df <-  structure(list(structure(c(1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 
    2L), .Label = c("row1", "row10", "row2", "row3", "row4", "row5", 
    "row6", "row7", "row8", "row9"), class = "factor"), treatment = c(0L, 
    0L, 34L, 75L, 46L, 85L, 24L, 87L, 43L, 12L), control = c(21L, 
    21L, 32L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 84L, 21L, 2L, 12L), control = c(21L, 
    78L, 98L, 12L, 13L, 87L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), treatment = c(21L, 
    321L, 87L, 54L, 45L, 45L, 0L, 98L, 45L, 0L), control = c(45L, 
    93L, 34L, 45L, 0L, 0L, 45L, 87L, 12L, 23L), treatment = c(34L, 
    0L, 0L, 34L, 0L, 23L, 5L, 76L, 9L, 0L)), .Names = c("", "treatment", 
    "control", "control", "treatment", "control", "treatment"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L))
```

Comment: `df[Reduce("&", lapply(split.default(df[-1], colnames(df)[-1]), function(a) rowSums(a > 0) > (ncol(a)/2))),]`

Comment: Thanks , it really works as expected. One quick question what if i want to use another value than 50%, let´s say 66% of each group ??

Comment: Just realized that in my original dataset my groups are unbalanced. I have 10 controls and 20 treatments. It will not work in that way ??

Comment: Can you provide the expected result for one or two rows? Like whether row1 or row2 should be included in the final output?

Comment: In the above example only row 10 is removed:
treatment = 12 , 0, 0 (2/3 are 0 = 66%). 
control has = 12,0,23 (1/3 is 0 = 33%).
So for row 10 we have one group with 66% of 0 (group treatment) and 33% of 0 in group control. Since both groups are not above 50% threshold the row is discarded.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you want, if a row has more than 3 "0", you want to remove the row.

```
rownames(df) <- df[,1]
df <- df[,-1]
df <- df[apply(df, 1, FUN = function(x){sum(x == 0)}) < 3,]
```

Row 10 is removed.

Comment: Not really, See my last comment on previous answer.